# Spree active shipping rails gem create_shipment method never called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I'm integrating spree with active shipping to use fedex in my e-commerce website, and it looks like active shipping is used only for retrieving rates and not for create labels or get tracking numbers, github docs are very poor on this matter too, someone can explain me if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, spree_active_shipping is used to calculate the amount for the shipping method during the checkout process. It's not used for fulfilling the purchase.